# Can i append an already existing div to another already existing div?

Tags: jquery, append

I have a contact form in a div on it's own with opacity 0, and a div where content is dynamically manipulated depending on what the user click on the menu.
After the user gets to the last stage of the menu i need to clear the content of the div that displays everything and then "move" the form div into it,
would something like this work?

```
$('#menu_form').on('click', function() {
    $('#form_div').append('#display_div');
});
```

So to recap 2 already existing divs, need to place one of them into the other on click.

Comment: i simplified things in the question, i need to modify multiple functions in order to get it to work with it, what i want to know is does append move the div into the other one?

Comment: but I don't think this works. You'll probably have to pull it out of the DOM, and reinject it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using `.appendTo()`

```
$('#menu_form').on('click', function(){
   $('#form_div').appendTo('#display_div');  // appendTo -> selector
});
```

Using `.append()`

```
$('#menu_form').on('click', function(){
   $('#display_div').append( $('#form_div') ); // append -> object
});
```

Comment: Hello, good answer, but it seems that appendTo "moving" content to the new DIV. At least I lost the source DIV by using that.

Comment: @ReddySK than use `.clone()` See the API documentation for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richardneililagan/EWGY5/) for a quick POC. Apparently it does.

The trick is to pass the object reference, not just the object id, like so:

```
$('#menu_form').on('click', function(){
    $('#form_div').append($('#display_div'));
});
```

You could also pass the current object, using `this`:

```
$('#menu_form').on('click', function(){
    $('#form_div').append(this);
});
```

Comment: cheers ^^ but Roko got it first gona accept his but u got an upvote so yeeey :P

Comment: HAHAHA, I don't mind not getting accepted. :D Glad to be of help though.