# Making button call multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

***Does anyone have a clue on how I can solve this please? Answer below doesn't work.***

I googled this question and found lots of answers but not suited to my problem.

I am trying to make a button call multiple functions (2 to be exact):

**JS**

```
  $(window).load(function(){
  $(function() { 
    $(".btn").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($(this).next(), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
        });
            }
        });
    });
}); 
});
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){
   $('canvas').appendTo('#here');  // appendTo -> selector
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Click</a>
```

I've tried the following: 
1. [Call two functions from same onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025138/call-two-functions-from-same-onclick) 
  2. [Can i append an already existing div to another already existing div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152315/can-i-append-an-already-existing-div-to-another-already-existing-div)

Which really sums up every other answer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click'(function(){
        callFunction1();
        callFunction2();
    });
});

function callFunction1(){
   $('#yourDivId').appendTo('#yourOtherDivId');
   console.log("what should function 1 do?");
}

function callFunction2(){
   console.log("What should function 2 do?");
}
```

Comment: **So do I add 'callFunction1' like this?**  `callFunction1(){ $('.btnSave2').on('click', function(){
   $('canvas').appendTo('#here');  // appendTo -> selector
}); }; `

Comment: @SteveGates nope, callFunction1 and callFunction2 are example names I used. You have to replace with your function calls.