# How to add existing div to a table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my html code like

```
<html>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td id="table_td">div here</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<div id="table_div">
    Hello
</div>
</html>
```

Expected is i need to add "table_div" to " table_td" dynamically

```
<html>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td id="table_td">
          <div id="table_div">
              Hello
          </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This should work `$('#table_td').append($('#table_div'))`.

Comment: [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) + [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152315/can-i-append-an-already-existing-div-to-another-already-existing-div

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append or http://api.jquery.com/appendto

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i append an already existing div to another already existing div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152315/can-i-append-an-already-existing-div-to-another-already-existing-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is jQuery `.append()` there is also `.appendTo()`

```
$( "#table_td" ).append( "<div id='table_div'>Hello</div>" );
```

For more details: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>clone demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <b>Hello</b><p>, how are you?</p>

 <script>
   $( "b" ).clone().prependTo( "p" );
 </script>
```